# Basic Python looping and appending

Tags: python

Write a program that takes a list and prints a message for each element in the list, based on that element's data type.

Your program input will always be a list. For each item in the list, test its data type. If the item is a string, concatenate it onto a new string. If it is a number, add it to a running sum. At the end of your program print the string, the number and an analysis of what the array contains. If it contains only one type, print that type, otherwise, print 'mixed'.

So the above is what I am trying to accomplish. And I am extremely new to all this so sorry if I don't make sense at times. Right now I am just trying to set up running through my list and appending any str to string list, and any int to my num list. Ive tried tons of ways and read documentation, and tried to search for help but I am either misreading stuff or just searching the wrong stuff. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
stuff = ['magical unicorns',19,'hello',98.98,'world']

string = []
num = []

for i in range(len(stuff)):
    if isinstance(i,str):
        string.append(value,i)
    if isinstance(i,int):
        num.append(i)

print (string)
print (num)
```

Comment: On the line `string.append(value,i)`, what is `value` supposed to be? It doesn't look like it's defined anywhere else.

Comment: Do you at least know what the expected output of your initial ``stuff`` list is? If you do then it should be easy for you to work your way towards the result. If you don't you should read the assignment again until you do.

Comment: value was not defined, you are correct. I was just trying different options to try and get something to work

Comment: yes, you need stuff[i] to get the member of stuff in position `i`. This applies to everywhere you've used 'i' within the For loop.. in fact fix that and you're nearly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for a quick, concise solution:

```
stuff = ['magical unicorns',19,'hello',98.98,'world']

s = ''.join(i for i in stuff if isinstance(i, str))

a = sum(i for i in stuff if isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, float))

print(s)

print(a)

if len(s) > 0 and a > 0:
   print("mixed")

elif len(s) > 0 and a == 0:
   print("string")

elif len(s) == 0 and a > 0:
   print("integer")
```

Output:

```
magical unicornshelloworld
19
mixed
```

Comment: "The array you entered is of mixed type"
"String: magical unicorns hello world"
"Sum: 117.98"

Comment: That is what my final output is to be

Comment: @Ajax1234- That is correct, besides the num would be the sum of 19 and 98.98. Warmley posted a solution to that above.

Comment: @RobertAmato Fixed now.

Comment: Really helpful stuff. That fixed the problem perfect!

Comment: simple edit to show the output properly    s = ',  '.join(i for i in stuff if isinstance(i, str))

Answer (score 0):

```
stuff = ['magical unicorns',19,'hello',98.98,'world']

string = []
num = []

for i in stuff:
    if isinstance(i,str):
       string.append(i)
    if isinstance(i,int):
       num.append(i)

print (string)
print (num)
```

Comment: That's just a copy&paste of the code from the question - how could this possibly be the answer?

Comment: @mpf82 : I guess it's not copy&paste .. for i in stuff and for i in len(stuff) differs

Comment: Sorry, so it's not copy&paste, but it's still incorrect (e.g. the undefined ``value`` is still there) and it would not print out the desired values.

Comment: He tried to do the `loop` and `append` the string + number to arrays.
I helped him with that.
Edit: took out the value error

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(stuff))
```

This will iterate over the **indexes** of your lists. So, you will only append this indexes to your list `num`.

Do the same loop but replace `for i in range(len(stuff))` by `for i in stuff`. With this, you will iterate over your list **elements**.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
stuff = ['magical unicorns',19,'hello',98.98,'world']

s = ""
num = 0
hasnum = False
hasstr = False

for i in stuff:
    if isinstance(i, str):
        s += i
        hasstr = True
    if isinstance(i, int):
        num += i
        hasnum = True

print (string)
print (num)
if hasnum and not hasstr:
    print "Only ints"
elif hasstr:
    print "Only strs"
else:
     print "Mixed"
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `type` instead of `isinstance`?

Comment: I just prefer the way it looks

Comment: But the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says "Object type comparisons should always use isinstance() instead of comparing types directly. "

Comment: a fastest way is to use filter function

 `hasnum = filter(lambda x:type(x)==int,stuff)
    hasstr = filter(lambda x:type(x)==str,stuff)
`

Comment: @Marco-That makes sense, I have not used lambda yet, I will research it.

Answer (score 0):

Think about python for loops as foreach loops in other languages. So we want to iterate over each item in the stuff list. 
We then want to make running totals of the strings and numbers.
Here is a simple loop which accomplishes this :)

```
from numbers import Number
stuff = ['magical unicorns',19,'hello',98.98,'world']

running_string = ''
running_total = 0

for item in stuff:
    if isinstance(item, basestring):
        running_string += item
    if isinstance(item, Number):
        running_total += item

print running_total
print running_string
if running_string and running_total:
    print 'mixed'
elif running_string:
    print 'string'
elif running_total:
    print 'int'
else:
    print 'empty'
```

Comment: @Warmley- What does the top line accomplish? from numbers import Number

Comment: Number is a python class which all numbers inherit from :)

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/numbers.html?highlight=number#module-numbers